# What do Jehovah's Witnesses believe about the activities of the antichrist in these "last days"?

Tags: jehovahs-witnesses, antichrist, tribulation

The Bible warns against the activities of deceivers and false prophets who arose during the first century, and continues to warn against their activities during the "last days".  Here are a few relevant Bible verses:

> But every inspired statement [every spirit] that does not acknowledge [confess] Jesus [is not from God] does not originate with God.  Furthermore, this is the [spirit of the ] antichrist's inspired statement that you have heard was coming, and now it is already in the world (1 John 4:3 Revised New World Translation)
>
> For many deceivers have gone out into the world, those not acknowledging Jesus Christ as coming in the flesh.  This is the deceiver and the antichrist.  (2 John 1:7 (Revised New World Translation)
>
> Let no one seduce you in any manner, because it will not come [the day of Jehovah] unless the apostasy comes first and the man of lawlessness gets revealed, the son of destruction.  He is set in opposition and lifts himself up over everyone who is called "god" or an object of reverence, so that he sits down in the temple of The God, publicly showing himself to be a god. (2 Thessalonians 2:3-4 New World Translation 2006)

Has the man of lawlessness, the son of destruction and the antichrist been revealed yet? What is "the temple of The God" in 2 Thessalonians 2:4?  What activities today identify the antichrist in these, the "last days" leading up to the tribulation prior to "the day of Jehovah"?

What is the official view of Jehovah's Witnesses regarding the antichrist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the official web-site of the Watchtower Society, I read the article, “Who is the Antichrist?” as posted by them at http://www.jw.org/en/publications/magazines/wp20150601/who-is-the-antichrist/    From their own statements in that 1 June 2015 article they say that

> “the antichrist is, not an individual, but a collective term. People
>   or organizations making up the antichrist spread lies, deny that Jesus
>   is the Christ, or the Messiah, and try to distort the relationship
>   between God and His Son, Jesus Christ. Those who make up the
>   antichrist claim to be Christ or his representatives, but since “they
>   went out from us,” they deviated from true Bible teachings.
>   Furthermore, this group was present at the time when John wrote his
>   letter, in “the last hour,” presumably the end of the time of the
>   apostles.”

They use 2nd John verse 7 to explain that “John understood the antichrist to be all who deliberately spread religious deception about Jesus Christ and Jesus’ teachings.” That is quite general, but do they state anything specific about today? Yes, indeed.

> “What about today? People and organizations making up the antichrist
>   still oppose Christ and his teachings. They deliberately spread lies
>   and deceptions with the intent of confusing the identity of the
>   Father, Jehovah God, and of His Son, Jesus Christ. We have good reason
>   to beware of such religious deceptions. Let us look at two examples.
>   For centuries, the churches propagated the doctrine of the Trinity,
>   claiming that the Father and the Son are part of the same entity. The
>   antichrist thus shrouds in mystery the identity of Jehovah God and
>   Jesus Christ… The churches add to the confusion by promoting the use
>   of Bible translations that omit God’s personal name, Jehovah, from the
>   text…"

Those are two examples in that article, which show that Jehovah’s Witnesses teach that all who propagate the doctrine of the Trinity, and churches that promote use of Bible translations not using ‘Jehovah’ in the text, are the antichrist. They should have a read of Young’s Literal Translation of the Bible, for it has ‘Jehovah’ in the Hebrew scriptures thousands of times. The 2004 edition published by Greater Truth Publishers should surely warrant the Watchtower Society clearing them of the charge of ‘antichrist’? Oh, but if those religious publishers uphold the Trinity doctrine, they would fall at that first hurdle. The second hurdle is not promoting the name ‘Jehovah’. Given those two hurdles that have to be cleared to avoid the label of ‘antichrist’ (in the estimation of Jehovah’s Witnesses), it would appear that there can hardly be a Christian religious group today not considered to be antichrist by them.

Comment: Jehovah's Witnesses have long used and even distributed Young's Literal Translation. https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1101993037?q=Young%27s+Literal+translation&p=par#h=8 Notice though that the antichrist is people who "deliberately spread lies and deceptions". We don't go around labeling everyone as the antichrist.

Comment: Anything specific to the last days?

Comment: @4castle  I never said JWs "go around labeling everyone as the antichrist." If you know of religious groups they believe are NOT antichrist, please just provide such a list of names. I would not expect the religious publishers of Young's Literal Translation to be on it, as they promote the Trinity doctrine - a second identifying mark of what, to JWs is the antichrist. The article I quoted from shows that either that, OR not promoting use of 'Jehovah' in the Bible identifies the antichrist, to JWs.

Comment: @Kris The two specific examples given in that Watchtower article refer to now as much as to past centuries. As JWs believe we are living in the last days now, that article is very specific about how to identify the antichrist in these last days.

Comment: So Jehovah's Witnesses believe that the antichrist is any Trinitarian denomination because they deliberately spread lies and deception about Jehovah and Jesus. "Because they are false prophets, one of their main objectives is religious deception... The engrafting of the Trinity was a masterstroke of the antichrist, for this doctrine shrouded God in mystery and blurred his relationship with the Son." Watchtower 2006 Why Identify the Antichrist?  The Antichrist Is Anti-Christian: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/pc/r1/lp-e/1200270383/2/6  Interesting.